# jQuery Select by ID Fails with Trailing Hyphen

Tags: jquery

I am selecting all divs that match a certain format (`edit-invoices-##_[a-zA-Z_-]`) and then grabbing their ids to use in further code, this works if I do the following:

```
var fields = $("#invoicesTable div[id|='edit-invoices']").map(function() { 
    return this.id; 
}).get();
```

However it will fails (returns no results) if I add a hyphen after invoices like so:

```
var fields = $("#invoicesTable div[id|='edit-invoices-']").map(function() { 
    return this.id; 
}).get();
```

The reason this is important is that if I have the following divs they would need to be treated differently so i have to select them separately:

```
edit-invoices-39_id
edit-invoices_products-39_id
```

Can anyone tell me why the trailing hyphen breaks the code?

Comment: [`jQuery( "[attribute|='value']" )`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/): Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or **starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `^=`

```
var fields = $("#invoicesTable div[id^='edit-invoices-']").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

As Andreas pointed out, the `|=` actually searches for that string PLUS a hyphen so when you added the trailing hyphen, jQuery was looking for edit-invoices--, I believe.

[jQuery Reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VVe5t/)

Comment: Just added a jsFiddle to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `|=` stands for [prefix selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either
>   equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a
>   hyphen (-)

So if you use this selector it will add the `-` at the end of the given value.

Ex:
`$("#invoicesTable div[id|='edit-invoices']")`: will look for elements with id `edit-invoices` or `id` starting with `edit-invoices-`, in the same way `$("#invoicesTable div[id|='edit-invoices-']")` will look for elements with id `edit-invoices-` or `id` starting with `edit-invoices--`

Answer (score 0):

Why not without trailing hyphen render the divs without trailing hyphen
or try to escape them